# Java: System.arraycopy is not copying my arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array called "first" and another array called "second", both arrays are of type byte and size of 10 indexes.

I am copying the two arrays into one array called "third" of type byte too and of length 2*first.length as follow:

```
byte[] third= new byte[2*first.length];
for(int i = 0; i<first.length;i++){
    System.arraycopy(first[i], 0, third[i], 0, first.length);
    }   
for(int i = 0; i<second.length;i++){
    System.arraycopy(second[i], 0, third[i], first.length, first.length);
    }
```

but it is not copying and it throws an exception: ArrayStoreException

I read on the [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) that this exception is thrown when an element in the src array could not be stored into the dest array because of a type mismatch. but all my arrays are in bytes so there is no mismatch

what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: That loop is unnecessary if you use `arraycopy`. The other way around, `arraycopy` is not required if you use a loop because you're assigning the values yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You pass [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) the *array*, not the array element. By passing `first[i]` into `arraycopy` as the first argument, you're passing in a **`byte`**, which (because `arraycopy` is declared as accepting `Object` for the `src` argument) gets promoted to `Byte`. So you're getting `ArrayStoreException` for the first reason in the list in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29):

> ...if any of the following is true, an `ArrayStoreException` is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>
> The `src` argument refers to an object that is not an array.

Here's how you use `arraycopy` to copy two `byte[]` arrays into a third:

```
// Declarations for `first` and `second` for clarity
byte[] first = new byte[10];
byte[] second = new byte[10];
// ...presumably fill in `first` and `second` here...

// Copy to `third`
byte[] third = new byte[first.length + second.length];
System.arraycopy(first,  0, third, 0, first.length);
System.arraycopy(second, 0, third, first.length, second.length);
```

Comment: thanks to you all .. but I decided to accept this answer as for the explanation of my mistake ..

Answer (score 2):

```
System.arraycopy(first, 0, third, 0, first.length);
System.arraycopy(second, 0, third, first.length, second.length);
```